# create a batch of random matrices

Tags: c++, arrays, database, list, pointers

i want to create a batch of matrices of random sizes (10-1000) and random data. i need to somehow arrange this batch so i can use it in later data processing, so they need to be accessed one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <list>;



unsigned char* createAMatrix(int width,int hight){
    unsigned char mat[width][hight];
    unsigned char* ptr;
    srand(100);
    for(int row=0;row<hight;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<width;col++){
            mat[row][col]=rand();
        }
    }
    ptr=&mat[0][0];
    return ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::list<unsigned char*> matList;

    //create a batch of matrixes
    int batchSize=1;
    srand(100);
    for(int k=0;k<batchSize;k++){
        //set 10-1000 hight & width
        int matWidth=rand()%990+10;
        int matHight=rand()%990+10;
        //create matrix
        matList.push_back(createAMatrix(matWidth,matHight));

    }
}
```

this is what i have so far and i'm having trouble deciding whats the best way to address this issue being pointers or another method? is using a list the best way to store them?

BTW i know there are problems in the code.. it is under debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned char mat[width][hight];` is a local variable and goes out of scope when function `createAMatrix` returns. You have to allocate dynamic memory. Adapt your code like this:

```
unsigned char* createAMatrix(int width,int hight){
    unsigned char* ptr = new unsigned char[width*hight];
    srand(100);
    for(int row=0;row<hight;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<width;col++){
            ptr [row*hight+col]=rand();
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Note, you have to `delete` the allocated memory at the end of your program.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::list<unsigned char*> matList;

    //create a batch of matrixes
    int batchSize=1;
    srand(100);
    for(int k=0;k<batchSize;k++){
        //set 10-1000 hight & width
        int matWidth=rand()%990+10;
        int matHight=rand()%990+10;
        //create matrix
        matList.push_back(createAMatrix(matWidth,matHight));

    }

    for ( std::list<unsigned char*>::iterator it = matList.begin(); it != matList.end(); it++ )
        delete *it; 
}
```

I recommend to use `std::vector` instead of dynamic memory allocation. Here is a solution for `std::vector<std::vector<unsignd char>>`

```
void createAMatrix(int width,int hight, std::vector<std::vector<unsignd char>> &mat ){
    srand(100);
    mat.reserve( hight );
    for(int row=0;row<hight;row++){
        mat.push_back( std::vector(width) );
        for(int col=0;col<width;col++){
            mat.back().push_back( rand() );
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: i have considered using vectors but i cant decide. an array was chosen with no justification over a vector.. can you help me justify the usage of a vector over an array?